# Android Wearables: How to listen for any incoming notifications received in wearable side in android

Tags: android, wear-os

How to use Wearable Data Layer APIs to listen for incoming sms notifications received on android wear side.

Answer (score 0):

Google has a simple tutorial online shows you how to use Data Layer APIs which you can check [here](http://developer.android.com/training/wearables/data-layer/data-items.html#ListenEvents). If you want to have a background service that can receive data changed events then you can implement the WearableListenerService which you can find a sample from [here](http://developer.android.com/training/wearables/data-layer/events.html#Listen).

Comment: Just like NotificationListenerService listen notification received on android mobile. The same I want to listen for atleast sms notification received in android wear side. I had already tried the above links but could not come to the answer!

Comment: I don't think you can use NotificationListenerService or find similar services on android wear side. Android Wear is not as opened as Android OS, and you can probably find people asking similar questions online. However, you can implement NotificationListenerService on your phone side and passing the notifications to wear using Data Layer API.